# why my application doesnt finish spark

Tags: memory, apache-spark, cluster-computing

i run a spark application (input 90Mo), according to jobs UI all my jobs has completed but i notice that my application doesn't finish , this is the last messages ( why i don't get that the SC has successfully stopped )

> 16/09/13 02:17:31 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 15 finished: saveAsTextFile at slowlyChangingDimension.java:244, took 1,222274 s
>   16/09/13 02:17:38 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_49_piece0 on 10.0.10.45:46789 in memory (size: 26.2 KB, free: 1424.7 MB)
>   16/09/13 02:17:38 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_49_piece0 on 10.0.10.51:54860 in memory (size: 26.2 KB, free: 1424.7 MB)
>   16/09/13 02:17:38 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_48_piece0 on 10.0.10.45:46789 in memory (size: 4.4 KB, free: 1424.7 MB)
>   16/09/13 02:17:38 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_48_piece0 on 10.0.10.53:56003 in memory (size: 4.4 KB, free: 1458.5 MB)
>   16/09/13 02:17:38 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_48_piece0 on 10.0.10.47:51300 in memory (size: 4.4 KB, free: 1458.5 MB)
>   16/09/13 02:17:38 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_48_piece0 on 10.0.10.51:54860 in memory (size: 4.4 KB, free: 1424.7 MB)
>   16/09/13 02:17:38 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_48_piece0 on 10.0.10.54:44644 in memory (size: 4.4 KB, free: 1458.6 MB)
>   16/09/13 02:17:38 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_48_piece0 on 10.0.10.52:32794 in memory (size: 4.4 KB, free: 1458.6 MB)
>   16/09/13 02:17:38 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_47_piece0 on 10.0.10.45:46789 in memory (size: 26.2 KB, free: 1424.7 MB)
>   16/09/13 02:17:38 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_47_piece0 on 10.0.10.48:54348 in memory (size: 26.2 KB, free: 1458.6 MB)
>   16/09/13 02:17:38 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned shuffle 28

Comment: Is it the Spark Batch application or Spark Streaming application?

Comment: batch application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As this is the batch application. You should use **`context.stop()`** at the last line of program, then it will work fine. 
If it is not the case then can you share the code that you are running.